# Экранирование витой пары, разница S/FTP(SF/UTP), SF/FTP, SFTP

Tags: сеть

Читал с программы "Сетевой инженер" о витой пары, дошёл до маркировки SFTP и офигел, описание вроде не соответствует фотографиям, объясните какое экранирование у S/FTP, SF/FTP,SF/UTP[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

U/UTP: без экрана
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

F/UTP: фольга под внешней оболочкой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

S/UTP: оплетка под внешней оболочкой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SF/UTP: фольга и оплетка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

U/FTP: пары в фольге
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

F/FTP: еще больше фольги
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

S/FTP: пары в фольге и оплетка сверху
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SF/FTP: оплетка и фольга и каждая пара в фольге
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в маркировке нет / то подразумевается `* /U TP`